# How to convert JSON strings with different content but in same structure to C# objects?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

ı have a Xamarin Forms project. In a part of this project, I need to retrieve data from database in a form of JSON string however this data may change in number of roots and values and root names. All retrieved strings are in same structure however, All information in strings are different.

An example string:(In original it is a single line.)

```
{
    "20Pr": {
        "20Pr": {
            "AA": "0:0:0",
            "EE": "1:0:4",
            "Comp": 0,
            "ASE": "0:0:0",
            "PES": "1:0:0",
            "PLD": "0:0:4",
            "ASET": "0:0:0"
        },
        "22Bp Cache": {
            "AA": "0:0:0",
            "EE": "1:0:1",
            "Comp": 0,
            "ASE": "-",
            "PES": "1:0:0",
            "PLD": "0:0:1",
            "ASET": "-"
        },
        "21SSL Fail": {
            "AA": "0:0:0",
            "EE": "1:0:1",
            "Comp": 0,
            "ASE": "-",
            "PES": "1:0:0",
            "PLD": "0:0:1",
            "ASET": "-"
        }
    },
    "40godown": {
        "43Sw & DB": {
            "AA": "0:0:0",
            "EE": "1:24",
            "Comp": 0,
            "ASE": "-",
            "PES": "1:1:4",
            "PLD": "0:0:1:0",
            "ASET": "-"
        },
        "40goown": {
            "AA": "0:0:0",
            "EE": "1:24",
            "Comp": 0,
            "ASE": "0:0:0",
            "PES": "1:0:4",
            "PLD": "0:2:0",
            "ASET": "0:0:0"
        }
    }
}
```

Only the AA,EE,Comp,ASE,PES,PLD,ASET are constant but their values are not constant.

Is it possible to create C# objects from changing JSON strings without having information about names as "40godown"?

Comment: It really depends on how you want this to work, but a custom deserializer with JSON.NET would work. Each child object child be deserialized to the same object type since the structure doesn't change but you could create dictionaries/whatever other data structure you need to contain the sets of objects. Are we always talking one parent then multiple children or could there be additional levels of nesting etc?

Comment: Yes, It always have one parent and multiple children and there are consequtive 6 or 7 parents like this. To illustrate, in the sample string in question, "20Pr" and "40godown" are parents and each have 3 children. @Charleh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have defined a class `Thing` that has `AA`, `EE`,..., `ASET` properties, you can deserialize that JSON into `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Thing>>` without loosing information.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Thing>>>(json);
```

Comment: You know I actually saw someone manually parsing JSON recently in .net ... I told them about deserialization and they told me they didn't have time to learn anything new.

Comment: @Charleh Newtonsoft.Json is 10 years old. Obviously it isn't something new. I'm programming for 40 years, almost every day I learned something new and I'm still learning. I don't understand programmers who refuse learning new things.